# How to scan LocalDateTime correctly?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

We are required to use the input format

```
dd.MM. HH:mm
```

for the Scanner (without using extra variables!), how can I get these scanned values into the start variable?

My program doesn't work. Always prints "Invalid input!" although my input doesn't seems to be wrong:

```
System.out.println("Start:");
sc.nextLine();
sc.findInLine("(\\d\\d)\\.(\\d\\d)\\. (\\d\\d):(\\d\\d)");
try{
    MatchResult mr =sc.match();
    int month = Integer.parseInt(mr.group(2));
    int day = Integer.parseInt(mr.group(1));
    int hour = Integer.parseInt(mr.group(3));
    int minute = Integer.parseInt(mr.group(4));
    LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.of(year, month, day, hour, minute);
    System.out.println(start);
} catch (IllegalStateException e) 
{
    System.err.println("Invalid input!");
}
```

My input:

20.08 13:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't call `sc.nextLine();` after printing `Start:`. This effectively tell the Scanner to read the line `20.08. 13:00` you are printing and ignoring it since you're not storing the result. Then, when you're calling `findInLine`, the scanner attempts to match the next input line (for which I guess is empty and you just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> a second time) but fails.

Then, since no match was made, [`sc.match()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#match--) throws an `IllegalStateException`:

> Returns the match result of the last scanning operation performed by this scanner. This method throws `IllegalStateException` if no match has been performed, or if the last match was not successful.

So the corrected code would be:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Start:");
// sc.nextLine();  <-- don't do that, this reads and ignore your input
sc.findInLine("(\\d\\d)\\.(\\d\\d)\\. (\\d\\d):(\\d\\d)");
try {
    MatchResult mr = sc.match();
    int month = Integer.parseInt(mr.group(2));
    int day = Integer.parseInt(mr.group(1));
    int hour = Integer.parseInt(mr.group(3));
    int minute = Integer.parseInt(mr.group(4));

    LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.of(2015, month, day, hour, minute);
    System.out.println(start);
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    System.err.println("Invalid input!");
}
```

Comment: @Johnny Beware that the input in your question is `20.08 13:00` which is missing a dot, it should be `20.08. 13:00`. Did you test with that?

Comment: Hey man thanks a lot!!!! Finaly it works :-)

My input was constantly wrong, the last dot was missing all the time!